# Associate an arbitrary method with another method in Java?

Tags: java

I am (supposed to be) creating a simple menu display. My Menu class creates a List of MenuOption objects and these can be displayed and selected, etc. A programmer can add options to the List in the Menu class, optionList, using the addOption method.

What I want to be able to do is make it so the programmer can associate any arbitrary method from one of his or her other classes with a specific option.

For example, I want it so if the programmer typed something like:

```
menu.addOption("Print a roster", roster.print());
```

then the addOption method would do something like this:

```
optionList.add(new MenuOption("Print a roster", roster.print()));
```

and then, henceforth, the method roster.print() would be associated with the menu option text "Print a roster" so if a user chose "Print a roster," roster.print() would be called.

===============================================

By the way, I have started looking into the new Lambda Expressions from Java 8, but I'm not quite sure how they work or if they provide the necessary approach I would need to achieve my desired effect.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the `MenuOption` constructor would have to be a `Runnable`, and you would be able to supply

```
roster::print
```

as a value.  This is called a [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), and is just syntactic sugar for creating an object that implements a [Functional Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) (in this case [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html)).  It could also be written as

```
() -> roster.print()
```

On button click you would need to call the `run()` method.

Comment: Perfect! I looked a bit more into how functional interfaces worked, and I figured it out without much trouble. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I have come across something I don't know how to do though--what if my arbitrary method may or may not be passed parameters? For example, let's say the print method is overloaded, so it could be called as `roster.print()`, or, if I want it to accept a String[] arr I have created, it could be called as `roster.print(arr)`. Is it possible to implement this version of the print method which contains parameter(s) into the lambda expression?

Comment: The method with and without parameter are two entirely different methods.  For the version with a `String[]` parameter` your `MenuOption` constructor would have to accept a `Consumer<String[]>`.  I'm not sure if you'll still be able to use a method reference (because of the ambiguity, although theoretically it could be inferred), so you may need to pass the lambda `(arr) -> roster.print(arr)`.